# Backend Category count is right but displaying products

Tags: product, category, category-products

I am a bit confused as to why my category has the right product count for the category, but when I look at Category Products there are 0 products in there. Why is this happening? When I go to the Front-end all the products are there.

Answer (score 1):

May it, that the category is an anchor category, therefore all products of all subcategories are in it.

Comment: even if its the anchor, shouldnt i be able to view all the products still?

Comment: Afaik (didn't check) are products added implicit (via subcategory) and explicit via list. If the list is empty - it's empty :)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to re-index your data.  We had a similar issue where category counts were right but all the products didn't show and it was imply that the category was pulling from the index, yet the category count wasn't.